# List files and ignore permissions errors

Tags: awk, grep, find, stderr

I need to make a list of files bigger than 10G that will be the ignorefile input for a duply backup. However, I have some files which I don't have permissions to read. I want to ignore those that will be handled later and make the list clean with out the 'Permission denied' message.

I can make the list like this:

```
$ find data/ -size +10G
/data/bigfile1
find: `/data/badfile1': Permission denied
find: `/data/badfile2': Permission denied
/data/bigfile2
```

Then I need to remove the lines that contain the 'Permission denied' or 'find:' strings. I'm not sure if the order of the list output is relevant, but that's what I'm seeing. I'm trying several options but can not manage to remove the lines. I'm following this question, that seems similar but I don't understand why it doesn't work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo

I'm trying to ways, first with grep:

```
$ find data/ -size +10G | grep -v 'find:'
find: `/data/badfile1': Permission denied
/data/bigfile1
find: `/data/badfile2': Permission denied
/data/bigfile2
```

Also using awk:

```
$ find data/ -size +10G | awk '!/find:/'
find: `/data/badfile1': Permission denied
find: `/data/badfile2': Permission denied
/data/bigfile1
/data/bigfile2
```

In any case the positive selection works fine. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: `find [....] 2> /dev/null`.  What you're seeing is standard error output, which is not sent into the pipeline, so `grep` will not see it, nor will any other things in a pipeline.  You can see this by running your `find` command and sending the output into a new file; you will not see the errors in the new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## IO Redirection

The problem is not with your script, but is a *feature* of UNIX IO redirection.

Consider, the following command

`find data/ -size +10G | grep -v 'find:'`

only the `stdout` stream is being sent to the piped `grep` command, the error messages are in a seperate output stream, `stderr`.

So, even though you are seeing the error messages in your terminal session, due to the fact that the terminal is printing both `stdout` and `stderr` to the console, your `grep` command is *not* receiving those lines of output. This is due to how the `|` redirects output. The pipe `|` only connects `stdout` to the next command's `stdin` so the `stderr` does not go into the next command.

Most `*NIX` utilities function this way, sending errors to the `stderr` output stream so that in situations like you are encountering there is no need to filter these messages out.

### Testing

To see what the exact `stdout` of the above command will be when it is passed to `grep` do the following:

`find data/ -size +10G > out.txt`

You should still see the errors in your console, but the `stdout` output stream will have gone to a new file, `out.txt`. Look in there and you will not see the lines of error messages.